# Entity Framework. Custom property initialization

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I need to store an object settings in Database and to make the model simpler I want to store them as XML\JSON in string column.

However, when they are read from  database I need them converted to the collection of objects that is a property.

I wonder if I can customize the way EntityFramework initializes property or saves value in database.

Alternatively, I can create a separate type in data layer that is used for saving data in database, but in that case I'll probably lose IQueryable capability for original type.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past, using this little trick:

```
public class DemoEntity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }

    public string JSONData
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data);
        }
        set
        {
            Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

`JsonConvert` is the Newtonsoft conversion class, which you can get from NuGet. Entity Framework ignores `Data`, and you ignore `JSONData`. On saving to the database, Entity Framework will use the getter for `JSONData`, and get a JSON string containing the `Data` object. On loading from the database, Entity Framework will retrieve the JSON string, and use `JSONData`'s setter to try to set it, which will deserialise it and initialise `Data` with the resultant value.

One thing to note: this technique has issues with large amounts of data; if your serialised data ends up being over a few thousand characters then the `JsonConvert` class will start to throw errors, so you might want to add some logic to cut your data into smaller chunks and concatenate the resultant serialised strings, and vice versa for deserialisation.

Comment: Thanks, anaximander! In that case entity knows that data is stored in Json format. However, I want to make it persistent ignorant. For example, if I change database to MongoDb I will not need json as it supports dynamic schema.

Comment: This is a persistence-layer class, so it's kind of difficult to make it persistence-agnostic... You may be able to use EF's fluent config to customise the column mapping for that property. Or perhaps have an interface to represent a dynamically-mapped property, implement it for each (EF/MongoDb/etc) and use dependency injection. One question - how likely is it that you'll swap to MongoDb? It sounds like you may be hampering your ability to work in the system you *are* using because you're trying to make it compatible with a load of other systems you *aren't* using, and may never actually use.

Comment: In that particular case it is likely that underlying database might be changed. We plan to create a database for each particular user and it might be a requirement to store data in another system. That's why persistense layer must be fully separated from model.

I'm thinking about creating a derived type with String property and keep in database it's instances. The model can still work using base class interface.

Comment: Cool - just checking; there's a lot of questions that end up running into the YAGNI principle. In your case... I'd probably create an interface for dynamic data properties, and implement a different version for each DB type (one that serialises to JSON, one that uses MongoDb dynamic schema, etc). Then you can use dependency injection to provide the correct one at runtime. The bonus is you can set that up at the same time as setting up the injection of the data access classes, which is how I'd manage the whole "database type per user" thing.

Comment: Not quite sure I've got the idea of the interface. In simple scenario I have my model class Entity that have a property IList<String> Categories which I want to store in a single text column in database. This is a model class. EF use it for table mapping as well. Do I need another class for the Entity in Persistense layer?

Comment: I'd have an interface `IDynamicData`. Then you can have a class `JsonDynamicData<T> : IDynamicData<T>` that does what I described above, and a class `MongoDynamicData<T> : IDynamicData<T>` that uses MongoDb's dynamic schema, etc. Then, your model class has `IDynamicData<string> Categories` instead of that `IList`. Then when you configure your dependency injection to provide your Entity Framework class to meet your data access interface, you also map `IDynamicData<T>` to match `JsonDynamicData<T>`. So then when you instantiate this entity, it gets an instance of that class automatically.